# Can Google Earth images be imported?

Tags: web-access, geographics

I've searched for code and found nothing.  Is this a server handshake problem?

Below, GeoGraphics executes properly on wikimapia.org, but WebImage doesn't open earth.google.com to a coordinate.

```
(*This is the initial URL*)
WebImage["https://earth.google.com/web/"]

(*This will work in a new tab*)
WebImage["https://earth.google.com/web/@37.45444724,-94.6859694,291.\
40272002a,304.23014266d,35y,0h,0t,0r"]


(*From a stackexchange question*)
GeoGraphics[GeoCenter -> GeoPosition[{67.603, 161.976}], 
 GeoServer -> {StringTemplate[
    "http://i<*Mod[#2,4]+Mod[#3,4]*4*>.wikimapia.org/?x=`2`&y=`3`&\
zoom=`1`&lng=0"], "ZoomRange" -> {1, 22}}, 
 GeoRange -> Quantity[20, "Kilometers"], AspectRatio -> 1]
```